# how to keep list values even after AlertDialog disappear

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I made a list in my stateful widget class that is going to be filled with some values when the user selects cards, I have a showDialog function on a button in my app that every time it is clicked a form will be shown to the user.
the problem is after the user come back from the form by clicking on the Ok button the stateful class will be recreated and clean up all my list's values (the ActivityPeopleCard class called again)... how to keep the value of the list even after coming back from showDialog form?

```
class ActivityPeopleCard extends StatefulWidget{

  Activity activity;
  List<double> _cost ;
  ActivityPeopleCard({this.activity});

  @override
  _ActivityPeopleCardState createState() => _ActivityPeopleCardState();
}

class _ActivityPeopleCardState extends State<ActivityPeopleCard> {
  int _peopleIndex = -1;
   List<int> _peopleIndexes = new List();
   List<int> _longPressed = new List();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: height/2.6,

            child:new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.activity.peopleInvolved.length,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3), 

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onTap: ()=> setState(() => {

              }


              ),
              child: _buildWidget(index, context)
            );
        },

       ),

    );
  }

  _buildWidget(int index, BuildContext context){

    bool isSelected = _peopleIndexes.contains(index)?true:false;

    return new Card(

                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Stack(
                                  children:<Widget>[

                      new Container(
                      height: height/4,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
            width:height/15,
            height: height/15,

            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height/20),

              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width:2),


            ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height/15),
                            child: Image.asset(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].imagePath, fit: BoxFit.fill)),//CircleAvatar(

          ),

                          Center(child: Text(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].name))
                        ],

                      ),
                    ),
            shareTag(index, isSelected, context)
                    ])
              );
  }

  shareTag(index, isSelected, BuildContext context){
           return GestureDetector(
                      onLongPress: ()=>{

                        enterPrice(index, context),

                    },
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: isSelected ? true:false,
                      child: new Container(

                          height: height/2,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(

                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height/20),
                          color: Colors.red.shade500.withOpacity(0.7),
            ),
                          child: Center(child: SizedBox(

              width: width/4,
              height: height/15,

              child:Center(child: AutoSizeText("\$${ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index]}", style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Oxygen',fontSize: height/25),
               maxLines: 1,minFontSize: 5,textAlign: TextAlign.center,),

                        ),
                          ))),

                    )                       
                    );
  }



  enterPrice(int index, BuildContext context){
    //print("Long Pressed");
    showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(

                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
                    ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      content: Form(

                        //key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new TextFormField(
                              initialValue: ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index].toString(),
                           keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              cursorColor: secondColor,
                               style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1,),
                                autofocus: true,

                        decoration: new InputDecoration(

                        focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(

                               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                               borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                 color: secondColor
                               )),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                               color: firstColor
                               //decorationColor: Colors.yellow
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: firstColor,),
                          labelText: "Cost",

                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(

                               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                               borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                 color: Colors.black87
                               ),
                          ),

                        ),


                      ),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                });
  }
}
```

after the user come back from the form the _cost list will be initialized again with null and shows null values instead of previous values

Comment: Create a variable in your initial state that returns your Container. Then in your build method return your variable. This will stop the list refreshing/resetting every time the build method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in your initial state that returns your Container. Then in your build method return your variable. This will stop the list refreshing/resetting every time the build method is called

```
class ActivityPeopleCard extends StatefulWidget {
  Activity activity;
  List<double> _cost;
  ActivityPeopleCard({this.activity});

  @override
  _ActivityPeopleCardState createState() => _ActivityPeopleCardState();
}

class _ActivityPeopleCardState extends State<ActivityPeopleCard> {
  int _peopleIndex = -1;
  List<int> _peopleIndexes = new List();
  List<int> _longPressed = new List();
  var _vlContainer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vlContainer = myListContainer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _vlContainer;
  }

  myListContainer() {
    return Container(
      height: height / 2.6,
      child: new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.activity.peopleInvolved.length,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onTap: () => setState(() => {}),
              child: _buildWidget(index, context));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildWidget(int index, BuildContext context) {
    bool isSelected = _peopleIndexes.contains(index) ? true : false;

    return new Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: height / 4,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: height / 15,
                  height: height / 15,

                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 20),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 15),
                      child: Image.asset(
                          widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].imagePath,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill)), //CircleAvatar(
                ),
                Center(child: Text(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].name))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          shareTag(index, isSelected, context)
        ]));
  }

  shareTag(index, isSelected, BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () => {
              enterPrice(index, context),
            },
        child: Visibility(
          visible: isSelected ? true : false,
          child: new Container(
              height: height / 2,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 20),
                color: Colors.red.shade500.withOpacity(0.7),
              ),
              child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                width: width / 4,
                height: height / 15,
                child: Center(
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    "\$${ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index]}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'Oxygen',
                        fontSize: height / 25),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    minFontSize: 5,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ))),
        ));
  }

  enterPrice(int index, BuildContext context) {
    //print("Long Pressed");
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            content: Form(
              //key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextFormField(
                    initialValue: ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index].toString(),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    cursorColor: secondColor,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(color: secondColor)),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: firstColor
                          //decorationColor: Colors.yellow
                          ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.attach_money,
                        color: firstColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: "Cost",
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black87),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, if it is correct please mark it as the answer, otherwise tell me if you are still having issues.

Comment: as a matter of fact, I don't really know if your answer is correct because I've faced another problem with your code and the problem is I initialize the isSelected variable to true with its related card in the  onTap in myListContainer function I hope that every time the card will be clicked in shareTag function the visibility initialized by true and then I could see another container stacked but the thing is I can't see the changes reflected in UI even the isSelected variable is true. Do you have any idea what is the problem? why the UI is not synced by data changes

Comment: in your onTap you have the setState statement, you need to update your isSelected variable there and anything else you need the UI to update. Use the debugger to check if it is firing correctly,.

Comment: everything is correct but the problem is I don't see the UI changes according to the data. as you may notice from my code, in _buildWidget function my cards are made and the shareTag function in the stack is called but at first, because the isSelected variable is not true then container is not visible but after the user click on one of the cards i would expect that the isSelected turns to true and then I could see the container above that but it doesn't happen ... the thing is the isSelected variable is true when the user tap on the card but I don't see any changes on UI